# Dictionary comprehension to add two values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Wondering if you can use dictionary comprehension in Python to add two values together that are in a nested dictionary. See example below:

```
bal = {
    u'ARK': {'locked': u'0.00000000', 'free': u'1.10654000'},
    u'ARN': {'locked': u'0.00000000', 'free': u'0.33900000'},
}
```

I want to add keys 'locked' and 'free', and return the result as the value for the top level keys ('ARK', 'ARN', etc)

```
comb = {k: v[v + v] for k, v in bal.items() if v}
```

But I'm missing something and not really sure what it is... your help and advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show an example of the kind of output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that every values will be a dictionary with two keys: free and locked:

```
In [69]: {k: float(v['free']) + float(v['locked']) for k, v in bal.items()}
Out[69]: {'ARK': 1.10654, 'ARN': 0.339}
```

If your values is a dictionary, but the values might vary, it is simpler to create a function which converts all the strings to float, then take sum:

```
def sum_of_str(str_list):
    return sum(float(x) for x in str_list)

In [72]: {k: sum_of_str(v.values()) for k, v in bal.items()}
Out[72]: {'ARK': 1.10654, 'ARN': 0.339}
```